# Why is this Sevlte useSelector implementation not calling the derived function?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I've been trying to get Redux working in Svelte to make porting some React based code that use `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks simpler.

I found a useful [guide](https://edg.foo/blog/adding-redux-to-svelte) which leads to a Gist. I've gone through and implemented this approach (which I did manage to get a more primitive example working some months back) but now can't seem to get things going.

I've got a reproduction of my progress here https://svelte.dev/repl/9ae9be44ed814a2b857962aa191173ed?version=4.2.12 but essentially the bit I'm struggling with is the `useSelector` hook.

```
export function useSelector(selector, equalityFn) {
    if (!equalityFn) {
    equalityFn = (lhs, rhs) => lhs === rhs;
  }

    const store = getContext(STORE_KEY);
  let lastSelectorValue;

    return derived(store, ($state, set) => {
        console.log("This derived callback never fires");
        const selectorValue = selector($state);
        if (!equalityFn(selectorValue, lastSelectorValue)) {
            lastSelectorValue = selectorValue;
      set(lastSelectorValue);
        }
    });
}
```

For some reason when I set this up, the callback passed to derived never seems to get called.

Can anyone explain why this isn't working so I can fix the `useSelector`?

Comment: The callback will only run when there's actually a subscriber https://svelte.dev/repl/19a456ee673b4d36b885a0e4604b24e7?version=4.2.12